# A line is perpendicular on a plane if and only if it is perpendicular on every line from that plane.

Tags: geometry, definition, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I know the  following definition:

"A line is perpendicular on a plane if and only if it is perpendicular on every line from that plane".

I saw on internet that this is not true. Why?

Comment: Any lines means at least 1 line so it's obviously false.

Comment: in addition to the above comment, also see https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/parallel-perpendicular-lines-planes.html

Comment: @imranfat There I saw that my definition it's false.

Comment: It's true if you mean "every" instead of "any". Sometimes the word "any" is meant in this sense; it's ambiguous. Also: I presume you refer to lines in the plane that actually *meet* that line. Can two lines be perpendicular if they don't intersect? Depends on your definition.

Comment: @MPW Thank you. Actually this I wanted to write.

Comment: @ MPW I know that two lines are perpendicular iff  the angle determined by them is a  right angle.

Comment: You need a definition: what does it mean to say that a line $L$ is perpendicular to a plane $\Pi$? Until you have a definition to use, there’s no way you can make any valid statements. Indeed, when I took a course in solid geometry in high-school (this was in a previous geological era), the definition was that $L$ is perpendicular to $\Pi$ at a point $P$ of $\Pi$ if and only if $L$ is perpendicular to every line in $\Pi$ that passes through $P$. Then it’s up to you to show that it’s sufficient for $L$ to be perpendicular to two lines of $\Pi$ through $P$.

Comment: And the reason you saw it on the internet is SIWOTI.

Comment: @MPW  In general, two lines are perpendicular if and only if their vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: One normally only speaks of coplanar lines as being perpendicular or not. There needn't be a plane containing two given lines. However, one could generalize this as a statement about the *directions* determined by these lines (i.e., translate them to the origin and compare them there). That's what I meant when I said it depends on your definition of perpendicularity.

Comment: @ MPV This is my definition for perpendicularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite frankly, the claim that this is false seems to be fake news. This definition is [accurate](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/parallel-perpendicular-lines-planes.html).

Although, if you are working in non-Euclidean geometry, then I suppose you could alter the definition of perpendicular points to somehow force the definition to be true.

Clarification (special thanks to @Aretino):

> A line is perpendicular to a plane if it has only one point in common with the plane and is perpendicular to every line on the plane passing through that point.

Comment: So, what is the ''good'' definition?

Comment: @peter see my edit

Comment: I don't think this is a good definition, unless you allow two skew lines to be perpendicular – which would be at odds with the usual definition. I would rather state this definition as follows: "A line is perpendicular to a plane if it has only one point in common with the plane and is perpendicular to every line on the plane passing through that point".

Comment: @Aretino Good point. I have made that adjustment